# How to get all keys from a value for a dict of lists?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary in a format like this

```
d = {
    "Fruit_1" : ["mango", "apple"],
    "Fruit_2" : ["apple"],
    "Fruit_3" : ["mango", "banana", "apple", "kiwi", "orange"]
}
```

I'm passing a value as "mango" and I want to get all corresponding keys where only mango occurs. I am not able to get corresponding keys where ever value occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this perhaps:

```
d = {
    "Fruit_1" : ["mango", "apple"],
    "Fruit_2" : ["apple"],
    "Fruit_3" : ["mango", "banana", "apple", "kiwi", "orange"]
}

# list comprehension
mango_keys = [fruit for fruit in d.keys() if "mango" in d[fruit]]
print(mango_keys)       


# ['Fruit_1', 'Fruit_3']         


# or more traditional for-loop (but non pythonic)

for fruit in d.keys():
    if "mango" in d[fruit]:
        print(fruit)
```

Comment: I would suggest (as per 3 other solutions) it's better to iterate `dict.items` if you are going to use both key and value in your logic.

Comment: You can just use `for fruit in d` (you don't need the `.keys()`).

Comment: @jpp but the OP has mentioned **"want to get all corresponding keys"** in the questing. Hence, `dict.keys()`

Comment: @Alexander I thought "Explicit is better than implicit."

Comment: @BlackBeard, Extracting keys via `dict.items` is not implicit / non-standard, if you are using the values too!

Comment: it's better to use items so you don't have to use the key to access the value (since you're iterating on the dict)

Comment: @jpp but if I want  **only** keys why should I use `dict.items`?

Comment: @BlackBeard, I think you misunderstand. It's *not* what you **want**, it's what you **use** that matters.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops

Comment: you need the values, or you would not do `d[fruit]`

Comment: @jpp if you mean [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52643037/how-to-get-all-keys-from-dictionary-from-a-value/52643105?noredirect=1#comment92219291_52643105) then yes, I got the point. Thank you :)

Answer (score 9):

Iterate in `d.items` and check `mango` existence in value.

```
In [21]: [key for key,value in d.items() if 'mango' in value]
Out[21]: ['Fruit_1', 'Fruit_3']
```

Answer (score 2):

The naive approaches (looping through all items and looking for the fruit) work but have a high complexity, mostly if you have to perform a lot of requests. You could slightly improve it by replacing your `list` values by a `set` (for faster `in` lookup), but that would still be slow (`O(n**2)` => `O(n)` but room for improvement).

If you want to be able to perform those queries a lot of times, it would be better to rebuild the dictionary so lookup is very fast once built, using `collections.defaultdict`

```
d = {
    "Fruit_1" : ["mango", "apple"],
    "Fruit_2" : ["apple"],
    "Fruit_3" : ["mango", "banana", "apple", "kiwi", "orange"]
}

import collections

newd = collections.defaultdict(list)

for k,vl in d.items():
    for v in vl:
        newd[v].append(k)

print(newd)
print(newd["mango"])
```

this is the rebuilt dict:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'apple': ['Fruit_2', 'Fruit_3', 'Fruit_1'], 'orange': ['Fruit_3'], 'banana': ['Fruit_3'], 'kiwi': ['Fruit_3'], 'mango': ['Fruit_3', 'Fruit_1']})
```

this is the query for "mango":

```
['Fruit_3', 'Fruit_1']
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
>>> d = {
...     "Fruit_1" : ["mango", "apple"],
...     "Fruit_2" : ["apple"],
...     "Fruit_3" : ["mango", "banana", "apple", "kiwi", "orange"]
... }
>>> 
>>> [key for key, value in d.items() if 'mango' in value]
['Fruit_1', 'Fruit_3']
```

The idea is to iterate over the (key, value) itempairs and check each value for the existence of `'mango'`. If yes, keep the key.

Since you are new to Python here's the tradidtional `for`-loop logic:

```
>>> result = []
>>> for key, value in d.items():
...     if 'mango' in value:
...         result.append(key)
... 
>>> result
['Fruit_1', 'Fruit_3']
```

Answer (score 1):

For a single query, you can use a list comprehension. This will has O(*n*) time complexity *each time* you search a value:

```
res = [k for k, v in d.items() if 'mango' in v]
```

For multiple queries, you can use a `defaultdict` of `set` objects via a one-off O(*n*) cost:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dd = defaultdict(set)

for k, v in d.items():
    for fruit in v:
        dd[fruit].add(k)

print(dd)

defaultdict({'mango': {'Fruit_1', 'Fruit_3'},
             'apple': {'Fruit_1', 'Fruit_2', 'Fruit_3'},
             'banana': {'Fruit_3'},
             'kiwi': {'Fruit_3'},
             'orange': {'Fruit_3'}})
```

You can then use `dd['mango']` to extract relevant keys.