# Find a value in dict then get the key

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary

I'm using Python 3. I have 3 groups and in these groups I have multiple values. [image]

I have the value that I search and I want to get his group.  For example if I have `CCC` I need to get `GROUP 1` and if I have `HHH` I want the `GROUP 3` then do something according to the group.

So I think I gonna create a dict like this (tell me if I'm wrong) :

```
{
  'group1': {'AAA','BBB','CCC','DDD'}, 
  'group2': {'EEE','FFF','GGG'},
  'group3': {'HHH','JJJ'}
}
```

So I see that we can revert the dict to get the key from a value so I thought to do this :

```
dict = {
  'group1': {'AAA','BBB','CCC','DDD'},
  'group2': {'EEE','FFF','GGG'},
  'group3': {'HHH','JJJ'}
}

revdict = dict([(dict[key],key) for key in dict])

group = revdict['CCC']
if group == 'group1':
    # Do something
elif group == 'group2':
    # Do something
elif group == 'group3':
    # Do something
```

But I don't think it's the good way to do what I want. There is a way to do something like this :

```
if 'CCC' in dict :
    # Then get the current key. How ?
```

Or maybe I don't need to create dict but another things ? I open for all your suggestions.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your `revdict` solution. It can do everything you want. What's the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all keys from dictionary from a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52643037/how-to-get-all-keys-from-dictionary-from-a-value)

Comment: Because I don't know if this is a good solution. I don't know if revdict will slow down my script.

Comment: @Aran-Fey In fact the reverse dict willl not work because I have multiple values for 1 key so I'll get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'`

Comment: Ok, but if you invert the dict *correctly*, that would solve all your problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reversed `dict`, commonly called an inverted index, will fail because you are using sets as keys. Sets being mutable, they cannot be hashed to form a `dict` key. Instead, you probably wanted each *element* of a group to form a key.

You can rewrite the correct inverted index with a `defaultdict`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

groups = {
    'group1': {'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD'},
    'group2': {'EEE', 'FFF', 'GGG'},
    'group3': {'HHH', 'JJJ'}
}

inverted_index = defaultdict(set)

for name, group in groups.items():
    for element in group:
        inverted_index[element].add(name)

print('group1' in inverted_index['AAA']) # True
print('group1' in inverted_index['EEE']) # False
```

In an inverted index, an element may have multiple keys pointing to it (even though it is not the case in you data), this is why each value must be a `set` of keys.

If, as you seem to state it in the comments, your data is assured to only have one-to-one correspondences, then you can simply create a `dict`.

```
inverted_index = {element: name for name, group in groups.items() for element in group}
print(inverted_index)
```

### Output

```
{'AAA': 'group1',
 'BBB': 'group1',
 'CCC': 'group1',
 'DDD': 'group1',
 'EEE': 'group2',
 'FFF': 'group2',
 'GGG': 'group2',
 'HHH': 'group3',
 'JJJ': 'group3'}
```

Comment: Ok I see. But if I do `print(inverted_index['AAA'])` it returns `{'group1'}` how can I get just the string `group1`?

Comment: @John You do not want to do that. Since it may be that multiple keys are associated to a value. Having a single key associated to, say 'AAA', would overwrite any other found key.

Comment: Maybe I just have to create manually the good dict ? `d = {'AAA' : 'group1', 'BBB' : 'group1', 'EEE' : 'group2'}` etc...

Comment: @John No. The way I suggested can very easily be adapted to create a one-to-one inverted index. Do you understand what I mean when I say it's a bad idea?

Comment: @John I added the ouput format you wanted. Please make sure to understand what I am saying about one-to-one corresponce. Otherwise, it will eventually blow in your face when an element will be allowed to be in multiple groups.

Comment: But the output is the same as I wrote in my previous comment. Btw it's impossible that an element will be allowed to be in multiple groups. They are static

Comment: @John Good if you are sure an element cannot be in multiple groups, the second solution is what you want

Comment: Ok. But you're right if elements are not static your first solution is nice

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the `key` using *list comprehension* and only returning the `key` if the `str` you are looking for is in its `values`

```
d = {
  'group1': {'AAA','BBB','CCC','DDD'},
  'group2': {'EEE','FFF','GGG'},
  'group3': {'HHH','JJJ'}
}

a = [i for i in d if 'CCC' in d[i]]
# ['group1']
```

Comment: How can I do to get just the string and not `['group1']` without add [0] at the end ?

Answer (score 0):

I you insist on not using index for the key,

```
answer = None
for key in d.keys():
   if "CCC" in d[key]:
      answer = key
      break
```

*edit suggested by @Olivier

Comment: You should use a boolean for your answer instead of an empty string. Also, I suggest you break out of the loop when you found a match

Comment: Why boolean why not empty string?

Comment: A boolean is kind of off you are right. It would be better to use, say None, as default answer

Comment: Yes, but it is not unconceivable that a group is eventually called ""

Answer (score 0):

```
for k,v in dict.items():
   if 'CCC' in v:
      print(k)
```

you can't escape loops or reverse dicts. if you don't have memory constraints use your reverse dict.